# what is the type of string in boost

Tags: c++, string, boost

I am new to boost. I am using wstring in code but I think it would not be good to do that as it would not work on Linux.

Looking at some functions from boost, I noted that its string can be using where I can use wtring and string.

It seems more logical that I use boost string instead of std string as it seems boost string is more portable than std string.

so how string is defined in boost and how I can use it in my code as string type.

Is it a good idea to do this (use boost string instead of std string)?

I have code like this which seems to work:

```
    inline static bool IsDirectory(const wstring &path)
    {
        return is_directory(path);
    }
```

and

```
    inline static bool IsDirectory(const string &path)
    {
        return is_directory(path);
    }
```

Comment: Not much of anything uses wide strings. One argument is to use UTF-8 `std::string`s and convert them to Windows's UTF-16 as the last possible step.

Comment: `std::string` is as portable as C++ itself is. It's part of the standard library.

Comment: By the way, which Boost string are you referring to?

Comment: @JeroenBollen It is not :(. I am working on windows and if I define a I use string and define Unicode char set, I am getting compiler error. To fix the problem, I need to use wstring.

Comment: @mans You use `std::wstring` for UTF-16, and they are also part of the standard library. :P

Comment: @mans, Again, keeping the UTF-16 limited to just winapi functions is good when using other libraries. Anyway, you can attribute that to how the `path` class is constructed: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path

Comment: What is "boost string"? I guess you'd like to use [boost::filesystem::path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Class-path-Constructors).

Comment: @mans the problem why you have to use wstring is only because you use _tchar or wchar_t, likely. Of course std::string is portable, and I use it on windows every single day.

Comment: @sehe this is not true. If I change the type of application to Unicode, then I am getting error from windows API.

Comment: @sehe he means std::string is not so interoperable with xxxW versions of WinApi. The solution could be to use a portable layer, like Boost.Filesystem, instead of direct using of WinAPI.

Comment: "I am getting compiler error." --- That's because you are not using WinAPI correctly, not because `std::string` is somehow non-portable.